# PowerShell Where-Object vs. Where method

Tags: powershell

An interesting and weird thing I noticed writing PowerShell classes lines:

```
class A {

    [object] WhereObject(){
        return @(1,2) | Where-Object {$_ -gt 2}
    }

    [object] Where(){
        return @(1,2).Where( {$_ -gt 2})
    }
}

$a = new-object A
$a.WhereObject() # Throw exception Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.

$a.Where() # Works well
```

It looks like it is by design. Why does it work so?

**Workaround**

Function which explicitly convert "empty" value to $null:

```
function Get-NullIfEmpty {
   param(
       [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true)][array] $CollectionOrEmtpy
   )

   begin { $output = $null }

   process
   {
      if($output -eq $null -and $CollectionOrEmtpy -ne $null){
          $output = @()
      }
      foreach ($element in $CollectionOrEmtpy)
      {
          $output += $element
      }
   }

   end { return $output }
}
```

In this case, the method will look like:

```
[object] WhereObject() {
   return @(1,2) | Where-Object {$_ -gt 2} | Get-NullIfEmpty
}
```

I tried to return an empty array from the class method, but it is also tricky because for a regular function an empty array means "nothing" as well. If you have a call chain like method1 -> function -> method2 - method1 throw the same exception. Because the function converts an empty array to nothing.

So converting to $null is optimal in my case :)

Comment: The only difference that WhereObjectCommand does not write any result to pipeline in case no matches. But .Where extension occasionally return empty array :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- The (PowerShell v4+) **`.Where()` *method***, which is evaluated in *expression mode*, ***always* returns an instance of `[System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection[psobject]]`**:

  - If no input objects match, that instance is simply *empty* (it has no elements and its `.Count` property returns `0`).
- By contrast, the **`Where-Object` *cmdlet*** uses **pipeline semantics**, which implies the following output behavior:

  - If *nothing* is output (if nothing matches the filter script block), the return value is a "null collection", which is technically the `[System.Management.Automation.Internal.AutomationNull]::Value` singleton.
  - If a *single* item matches, that item is output as-is.
  - If *multiple* items match and they are collected in a variable / evaluated as part of an expression, they are collected in an `[object[]]` array.

---

**As for the specific symptom** - which [Bruce Payette's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50956909/powershell-where-object-vs-where-method/50957388#50957388) has since confirmed to be a *bug*.

- *Update*: The bug is **fixed since at least v7**; returning "nothing" (`AutomationNull`) is now coerced to `$null`; see the original [bug report on GitHub](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/7128).

An internal `[List[object]]` instance is used to collect the method call's output, executed via an internal pipeline. If that internal pipeline outputs "nothing" - i.e., `[System.Management.Automation.Internal.AutomationNull]::Value` - *no* object is added to the list. However, subsequent code assumes that there is at least one object in the list and blindly accesses index `0`, causing the error at hand.

A simpler reproduction of the problem:

```
class A {
  # Try to return [System.Management.Automation.Internal.AutomationNull]::Value
  # (which is what `& {}` produces).
  [object] WhereObject(){ return & {} }
}

$a = new-object A

$a.WhereObject() # Throw exception Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
```

**As for the desirable behavior**:

It seems that the fix will result in `$null` getting output if the method's code returns the "null collection", [using C#'s default-value feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/default-value-expressions) - see [this comment](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/7128#issuecomment-399276335).

Answer (score 6):

The `.Where()` operator *always* returns a `Collection<PSObject>`. The pipeline case however, returns nothing. This is a problem because the code that invokes the scriptblock expects there to be an object in the result `List` i.e. `result.Count == 1`. There are no objects in the pipeline case so you get an index-out-of-range error. So this is a bug. We should still generate an error but it should be "non-void methods must return a value" or some such. BTW - the [code in question is here.](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/c1c5344a8897262433141ecbc13bb06ac2c4bbef/src/System.Management.Automation/engine/lang/scriptblock.cs#L508)

Comment: As usual, thanks for the peek behind the curtain.
However, I don't think that a fix should result in a (different) error still being generated, given that _anything_ can be cast to `[object]` (at least in C#), and that something like `[object] (& {})` works fine (is a no-op).

Comment: Why $null cannot be result of the method which should return object? I would also does not expect exception from this situation...

Comment: No - the exception is a bug but nothing is not null. But maybe autoconverting nothing to null is the right answer here? Thoughts?

Comment: Returning $null in this case is what I implemented.

Comment: The one thing I don't like every time I should check for $null before iterating. because:

$null | Foreach-Object { $_.someprops.prop = "111" } # throws exception;

&{} | Foreach-Object { $_.someprops.prop } # no throw because no iterating;